# Conversion exception on wrong line

Tags: c#, type-conversion, except

I have a 2D list of stings and I'm converting some of them to doubles. This works perfectly on my PC but fails when someone uses a different decimal saparator for some reason

```
try
        {
            foreach (var line in data)
            {
                if (line[25] != "")
                {
                    double market_size = Convert.ToDouble(line[25].Replace(",", "."));

                    if (line[59] != "") Players.Add(new string[] { line[1], line[0], Proper_Name(line[58]), (Convert.ToDouble(line[59].Replace(",", ".")) * market_size).ToString(), market_size.ToString() });
                    else Players.Add(new string[] { line[1], line[0], "No player", "0", market_size.ToString() });
                    if (line[61] != "") Players.Add(new string[] { line[1], line[0], Proper_Name(line[60]), (Convert.ToDouble(line[61].Replace(",", ".")) * market_size).ToString(), market_size.ToString() });
                    else Players.Add(new string[] { line[1], line[0], "No player", "0", market_size.ToString() });
                    if (line[63] != "") Players.Add(new string[] { line[1], line[0], Proper_Name(line[62]), (Convert.ToDouble(line[63].Replace(",", ".")) * market_size).ToString(), market_size.ToString() });
                    else Players.Add(new string[] { line[1], line[0], "No player", "0", market_size.ToString() });
                    if (line[65] != "") Players.Add(new string[] { line[1], line[0], Proper_Name(line[64]), (Convert.ToDouble(line[65].Replace(",", ".")) * market_size).ToString(), market_size.ToString() });
                    else Players.Add(new string[] { line[1], line[0], "No player", "0", market_size.ToString() });
                    if (line[67] != "") Players.Add(new string[] { line[1], line[0], Proper_Name(line[66]), (Convert.ToDouble(line[67].Replace(",", ".")) * market_size).ToString(), market_size.ToString() });
                    else Players.Add(new string[] { line[1], line[0], "No player", "0", market_size.ToString() });
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception except)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Conversion error:" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + except.ToString());
            this.Close();
        }
```

First of all I think that this should work even when a comma is used instead of a dot but that's not my main issue. That is, that when I get an exception error it shows that the on the line 454, which is where the foreach cycle starts. 
I can't show the error message because it is in Czech but it basically states that it is a conversion error on line 454.

Comment: check out converting decimals properly between different cultures. https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/351186/decimal-parse-and-cultureinfo-for-decimal-separator

Answer (score 0):

The problem indeed seems to be with the decimal separator; your code is assuming that a dot is used, which is not always correct.

you can try to convert the strings to the selected separator, whatever it is, in something like this:

```
internal static string ReplaceWithDecimalSep(string input)
    {
        string firstReplace = input.Replace('.', (char)swUserPreferenceStringValue_e.swSeparatorCharacterForDims);
        string secondReplace = firstReplace.Replace(',', (char)swUserPreferenceStringValue_e.swSeparatorCharacterForDims);

        return secondReplace;
    }
```

which can then be converted to a double safely in a manner similar to the following:

```
internal static double ToLocalCultureDouble(string input)
    {
        string toConvert = ReplaceWithDecimalSep(input);

        double.TryParse(toConvert, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double result);

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is line a list of strings (e.g. `List<string>`)? Which line is 454?

The Convert class throw exception whenever a conversion doesn't work. You could try with `double.TryParse()`, which return true or false. If you like Convert then try `Convert.ToDouble(value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`, that should work in any culture if you have converted "," to "." first.

Comment: Yes, line is a List<string>. Line 454 is the line where the foreach cycle starts.

Comment: Then I guess line 454 is  `double market_size = Convert.ToDouble(line[25].Replace(",", "."));`. What does line[25] contain? Is there any characters that cannot be converted? "+" or "-" are not always converted propertly. Print the value to console or debugger and investigate.